# Error in biber (by way of latexmk) - texlive 2022

Tags: errors, biber, latexmk, texlive2022

The “normal” compilation of a rather complex (thesis template) latex file, in macOS Monterey Version 12.6, works flawlessly in TeX Live 2021 and TeX Live 2022, with the command `latexmk -time -shell-escape -synctex=0 -emulate-aux-dir -pdf -silent template`.

To speed up the testing of different variants of this template, I…

- make several copies of the source (each copy in each own folder);
- customize each of the copies as necessary; and
- run multiple instances of `latexmk`, one over each copy, with the command from above.

With TeX Live 2021, the script runs smoothly.

With TeX Live 2022, I get this error:
`/var/folders/f1/4fh25zqx0_bd81r_n925d_4r0000gp/T/par-6a6d6c/cache-ff0e0f52fce2a47a2eaf3d127e3cbc846f2f7d08/thin/biber: cannot execute thin binary /var/folders/f1/4fh25zqx0_bd81r_n925d_4r0000gp/T/par-6a6d6c/cache-ff0e0f52fce2a47a2eaf3d127e3cbc846f2f7d08/thin/biber (errno=8)`

I tried to run two biber instances (more or less) at the same time and there was no problem.  I guess the problem is related to the combination of `latexmk + biber`.

Can someone provide some insight on this biber's error message?

Comment: Biber saves a lot of files in a cache directory and every so often updates them.  (Run `biber --cache` to see where the cache directory os.)  A known problem is that sometimes the cache gets corrupted, although this is rarer now than in the past. Having 2 instances of biber running at the same time and both updating the cache is a recipe for problems.   I'd try rerunning biber without having two instances at the same time.   Then run your complex workflow again.  If that works, you've got your answer.

Comment: We are aware that the MacOS "fat" universal binary requires the `lipo` command to unpack the correct "thin" binary on recent MacOS. Please make sure you have the Xcode Command line tools installed - it's a free install from Apple. See for example https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-xcode-command-line-tools/

Comment: @PLK Thanks for your input.  I have the Xcode command line tools installed.  The problem is definitely with running two instances of biber simultaneously.  See my next comment.

Comment: @John Collins Thanks for your input.  I confirm the problem is with running two instances of biber simultaneously.  I believe this should be something biber should take care itself, unfortunately it doesn't! 

I was able to go around this problem by defining a shell script with the name `biber` and prepending its location to the PATH.  The script waits to acquire a flie system exclusive lock, calls the real biber, and then releases the lock.  With this workaround latexmk is using my biber-script and is working perfectly even with multiple LaTeX compilations simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by forcing different caches for different instances of `biber`. Just set the environment variable `PAR_TMPDIR` differently for the instances as this determines the cache location if set:

```
mkdir /tmp/bibercache{1,2}
PAR_TEMPDIR=/tmp/bibercache1 biber ...
PAR_TEMPDIR=/tmp/bibercache2 biber ...
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not really a solution, but rather my workaround to the problem!**

Context: in macOS, running two instances of `latxmk` at the same time, but in different folders.

Symptom: `latexmk` fails with a message “*cannot execute thin binary*”

Cause: `latexmk` is running two instances of `biber`  at the same time.

Diagnosis: `biber` uses its cahce directory to read and store data, and these actions are not properly protected for concurrent executions of `biber`.

Solution: ensure there is only a single instance of `biber` running by having `latexmk` call our own frontend for `biber`, which will acquire a file system lock before running the real `biber` and release this lock afterwards.

Implementation:

1. Copy the following bash script to some directory of your choice and name it `biber` (e.g., `$HOME/bin/biber`).  Remember to customize the `BIBER` variable in the script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Please set BIBER to the real biber command.
# Check its location with the command "type biber".
BIBER=/Library/TeX/texbin/biber

LOCKFILE=/tmp/biber.lock

_lock() { 
# Wait until the Lock File does not exists, then create it
 while ! { set -C; 2>/dev/null >$LOCKFILE; }; do :; done
}

_unlock() {
    rm -f $LOCKFILE
}

_lock
$BIBER $@
_unlock
```

2. Run as many instances of `latexmk` as you want with the following command. Please notice that `$HOME/bin` must be replaced by the name of the directory where you saved the bash script.

```bash
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH latexmk <your_flags> <your_latrex_file>
```